# Grouped UITableView

Tags: ios

У меня есть 9 значений, которые размещены в массиве, и мне их нужно поместить в сегментированую таблицу 3 в одном сегменте, 5 во втором, и 1 з третьем, буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: а в чем именно проблема? какая часть решения у вас вызывает затруднения?

Comment: как указать нужное количество целов в одном сегменте

Comment: ну например разделить массив на 3 массива и оперировать ими. Тогда в `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` возвращать количество элементов в соответствующем массиве и для ` 
- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` брать элемент из соответствующего массива

Comment: ето единственный метод???
или можно все таки сделать это как то с одним масивом?

Comment: можно с одним, просто кода больше и он некрасивый. Тогда в тех же методах, что я указал выше делайте switch и пишите если `indexPath.section == 0` брать с первого элемента массива, если `indexPath.section == 1` брать начиная с 3го, если ==2 брать с 8го

Comment: извините, какой бы метод посоветовали вы?

Comment: Все таки наверно надо больше деталей насчет того, что вам надо сделать. Можно еще сделать второй массив содержащий 'карту' элементов, типа такого @[3,5,1], тогда в каждой секции таблицы будет столько элементов, сколько указывает этот массив, и каждый элемент должен читаться из оригинального массива с индексом сумма всех предыдущих элементов массива-карты + индекс элемента в запрашиваемой секции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать отдельный массив-карту:

```
self.mapping = @[@1, @5, @3];
```

и на основании его элементов заполнять таблицу:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [return self.mapping[section] integerValue];
}
```

и

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //создать ячейку

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<indexPath.section; i++) {
        index += [array[i] integerValue];
    }
    index += indexPath.row;
    //в index содержится индекс нужной вам ячейки из массива
}
```